# Why is my image source having this issue?

Tags: html, css

just wondering how to fix the img src = "" problem. Im using atom.io and i'm trying to display a .jpeg photo for my website i'm making.

[image]

Comment: This error message sounds like your Safari doesn't have the Permissions to access that file. Can you check from the Finder -> right click on one of the images file -> Get Info -> At the bottom, Sharing & Permissions. What's set for "(Me)"?

Comment: You should show us some code sample in order for us to help you. But know that browsers are not allowed to see your local files since it would cause security issues. You should have your images inside your website folders if it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

That's a security feature that shouldn't be disabled. It's to stop pages from accessing your local file system and using the data present.

What you should do is install a development server:

- [Atom Live Server](https://atom.io/packages/atom-live-server)
- [Chrome Web Server Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)

And make sure that all your resources are in your project folder

```
--MyAwesomeWebsite
|-index.html
|-photos
  |-pic1.jpg
```

That way your img tag would use relative addressing

```
<img src='../photos/pic1.jpg'>
```

Assuming the above image is loaded from `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to relative paths and load these images without issue.  For example, rather than this:

```
<img src="file:///Users/[...]/birdie.jpeg" />
```

Switch to this:

```
<img src="birdie.jpeg" />
```

This works because `birdie.jpeg` appears to be in the same folder as your HTML file, `index.html`.

If you had your images in a sub-folder, you would still use a relative path:

```
<img src="photos/birdie.jpg" />
```

Comment: The browser will only try to resolve the URL after it will parse it as an absolute URL: that shouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<img src="'../Photos/birde2.jpeg">
```

to

```
<img src="Photos/birde2.jpeg">
```

you have added extra "'"

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help.

Comment: Still need help! lol my pictures are what they're supposed to be and where they're supposed to be (I THINK) but they won't load. What can I do about this?

Comment: did you try with .jpg? because I think you are using jpg images. Is this site online or local? Sometime if the JPG, JPEG not working, case sensitive. Check them too.

Comment: Yes I did. It's locally from GOOGLE IMAGES lol. So yes I did, no I typed it exactly as it was shown to me.

Comment: Are you using file path as

WebCourse FrontEndWebDeveloper/birdie.jpeg? or
WebCourseFrontEndWebDeveloper/birdie.jpeg? 

because error msg it showing space
And did you remove the photos folder?

Comment: Im using WebDeveloper Front End. Photos is the folder i'm using and i'm typing it as it was shown to me in a course i'm taking simply as what I can name it and its file format.

Comment: Look at the error in console, yoou are calling WebCourse FrontEndWebDeveloper not WebDeveloper Front End. Am I right?
can you show the the url in html file?